# get object from multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have multidimensional array like this

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "worker_id" => "1"
    "salary" => "100000"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "worker_id" => "2"
    "salary" => "80000"
  ]
]
```

i try get the object but didn't work

```
foreach ($request->salary as $data)
{
    ($data->worker_id);
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you tried $data['worker_id']? What kind of error did you get?

Comment: @WannyMiarelli yes i get error Trying to get property 'worker_id' of non-object

Comment: yes this is because it is an array and not an object, the -> accessor is only for objects, with arrays you should use the index $data['index'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

function arr2Object($arr) {
    if (is_array($arr)) {        
        return (object) array_map(__FUNCTION__, $arr);
    }
    else {        
        return $arr;
    }
}

$request = [ ["worker_id" => "1", "salary" => "100000"], ["worker_id" => "2", "salary" => "80000"]];

$obj = arr2Object($request);

foreach ($obj as $data) {
    echo $data->worker_id;
    echo $data->salary;
}
```

Comment: you can badge my answer.

Comment: you can vote and check it. and click on answer button.

Comment: done, i'm so embarrassed don't see the check button

Answer (score 0):

While He Zhi Yong answer may work to me it is more correct to access it as an array instead of an object.

```
$request = [ ["worker_id" => "1", "salary" => "100000"], ["worker_id" => "2", "salary" => "80000"]];

foreach ($request as $data)
{
    echo $data['worker_id'];
}
```